# coffeescript jquery rails Uncaught type error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a rails 3.1 app and I am making an ajax call with jquery when a user clicks a checkbox.

Everything seems to work as expected but I am getting the following error in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
(anonymous function)application.js:9329
jQuery.event.handleapplication.js:2966
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

here is the coffeescript that I have for the page that I am loading

```
jQuery ->
$(".checkbox").click ->
    current_id = $(this).attr("id") ->

    obj =
        url: "/challenge/public?id=" + current_id
        success: ( data ) -> alert data.result
        error: () -> alert "error"

    $.ajax(obj) ->
```

Comment: I use [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) to help out with my js conversion from time to time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the line

```
current_id = $(this).attr("id") ->
```

which is equivalent to

```
current_id = $(this).attr("id")(->)
```

`$(this).attr("id")` returns a string, so that's why you get an `object is not a function` error. Just ditch the `->`.